# how to target both an input and a select element with same class

Tags: css, grouping

How can I write this so it targets both elements without writing it twice

```
.field_with_errors input{
    color: red;
    background: #CEF6EC;
    border: 1px solid red;
}


.field_with_errors select{
    color: red;
    background: #CEF6EC;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

This does not work

```
.field_with_errors select input{
    color: red;
    background: #CEF6EC;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
.field_with_errors select,
.field_with_errors input {
    color: red;
    background: #CEF6EC;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

multiple css selectors must be separated with a comma. You have to repeat the whole selector for each of them, as above.

also, it's a common practise to have a line break after each comma, to keep your css more readable - it does not affect the result, so the following mean the same:

```
.field_with_errors select,
.field_with_errors input {
```

and

```
.field_with_errors select, .field_with_errors input {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
.field_with_errors input,.field_with_errors select{
    color: red;
    background: #CEF6EC;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```